# I need to parse a log file into multiple files based on delimiters

Tags: bash, file, shell, text-parsing, fileparsing

I have a log file  which i need to parse it into multiple files.

```
############################################################################################
6610
############################################################################################
GTI02152 I    gtirreqi 20130906 000034 TC SJ014825         GTT_E_REQ_INF テーブル挿入件数 16件

############################################################################################
Z5000
############################################################################################
GTP10000 I NIPS     gtgZ5000 20130906 000054 TC SJ014825         シェル開始
############################################################################################
```

I need to create files like 6610.txt which will have all values under 6610 like(GTI02152..) and for z5000(GTP10000) respectively. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the pattern for every file? `file1; ###; text; ###; <empty_line> ; file 2`??

Comment: No there is no empty line. I need to parse like below 6610; ###; text; ###; z5000; ###; text; ###;

Answer (score 1):

Below script would help you to get the information. You can modify them to create the data you require.

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=`cat data.dat | paste -d, - - - - - | cut -d ',' -f 2,4 > file.out`
$cmd

while read p; do
    fileName=`echo $p | cut -d ',' -f 1`
    echo $fileName
    dataInfo=`echo $p | cut -d ',' -f 2`
    echo $dataInfo
done< file.out
```

Comment: I think the `paste -d, - - - - -` assumes that each record is exactly 5 lines long.  Is this a correct assupmtion?

Comment: @AtomicToothbrush, I agree with you. I have done that assumption.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It is not exactly 5 lines long it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk styled answer:

I put the following into a file named `awko` and `chmod +x` it to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { p = 0 }    # look for filename flag - start at zero

/^\#/ { p = !p }   # turn it on to find the filename

    # either make a filename or write to the last filename based on the flag
$0 !~ /^\#/ {
    if( p == 1 ) filename = $1 ".txt"
    else print $0 > filename
    }
```

Running `awko data.txt` produced two files, `6610.txt` and `Z5000.txt` from your example data.  It's capable of sending more data lines to the output files as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Ruby as well:

```
ruby -e 'File.read(ARGV.shift).scan(/^[^#].*?(?=^[#])/m).each{|e| name = e.split[0]; File.write("#{name}.txt", e)}' file
```

Example output:

```
> for A in *.txt; do echo "---- $A ----"; cat "$A"; done
---- 6610.txt ----
6610
---- GTI02152.txt ----
GTI02152 I    gtirreqi 20130906 000034 TC SJ014825         GTT_E_REQ_INF テーブル挿入件数 16件

---- GTP10000.txt ----
GTP10000 I NIPS     gtgZ5000 20130906 000054 TC SJ014825         シェル開始
---- Z5000.txt ----
Z5000
```

Answer (score 0):

This script makes the following assumptions:

- Each record is separated by an empty line
- #### lines are purely comment/space filler and can be ignored during parsing
- The first line of each record (ignoring ####) contains the basename for the filename

The name of the logfile is passed as the first argument to this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# write records to this temporary file, rename later
tempfile=$(mktemp)
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "" ]] ; then
        # line is empty - separator - save existing record and start a new one
        mv $tempfile $filename
        filename=""
        tempfile=$(mktemp)
    else
        # output non-empty line to record file
        echo $line >> $tempfile
        if [[ $filename == "" ]] ; then
            # we haven't yet figured out the filename for this record
            if [[ $line =~ ^#+$ ]] ; then
                # ignore #### comment lines
                :
            else
                # 1st non-comment line in record is filename
                filename=${line}.txt
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < $1
# end of input file might not have explicit empty line separator -
# make sure last record file is moved correctly
if [[ -e $tempfile ]] ; then
    mv $tempfile $filename
fi
```

Comment: Apparently Linux and BSD (e.g. Mac OSX) have different versions of mktemp.  The above script work for Linux.  For BSD (OSX) use `$(mktemp -t splitfile)` instead